# Google using HTTP/2.0?

Tags: http, http2

Why is Google already using HTTP/2.0 as at this time there isn't any RFC for that (it was approved by the IETF on 17th February 2015 as a new standard). But I found out Google is using this. How could that be?

I'm getting this from Google (using google.de):

```
https://www.google.de/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: *****
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.08
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 18 Feb 2015 23:10:26 GMT
Expires: -1
Server: gws
Set-Cookie: ***
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2-14
```

Comment: Large parts of what is now HTTP/2 was implemented in their own SPDY protocol already. And maybe they just don’t want to wait for RFCs to go through, but rather implement it now? After all, two of their people were directly involved with working out HTTP/2, so they might have chosen to implement it as early as they could.

Comment: Possible. But this makes no sense because the wiedly used browsers are not even familiar with this new protocol. What benefit would this have?

Comment: Well what do you even mean by _“I found out Google is using this”_ exactly? Within their own Chrome browser they are free to implement what they want, when they want. That had SPDY implemented already, and Firefox followed closely.

Comment: When you go to google.com and look at the response from their server, they want to give you HTTP/2.0.

Comment: Not in my browser, I’m still getting HTTP/1.1. And not in an up-to-date Chrome either.

Comment: I added my headers got from Google to the question.

Comment: "The wiedly [sic] used browsers are not even familiar with this new protocol." You may want to check your facts. Current versions of Chrome and Firefox both support HTTP/2, although it's not enabled by default. It will be enabled by default in Firefox 36, which ships this month. Even preview builds of IE 11 also have HTTP/2 support enabled by default. That's every major desktop browser except Safari.

Comment: There's a lot more green in this table than there is red: http://caniuse.com/#feat=spdy

Comment: thanks for retagging. But when it's not enabled by default, why do they already use it?

Comment: This is for SPDY. SPDY is NOT HTTP/2.0. HTTP/2 was developed out of SPDY.

Comment: The Can I Use page combines both HTTP/2 and SPDY, because many (most?) browsers that support SPDY also support HTTP/2.

Comment: "But when it's not enabled by default, why do they already use it?" Why wouldn't they? HTTP/2 has significant benefits for many use cases, especially when you have as many users as Google. Why not enable HTTP/2 for the people who can benefit from it, the number of whom is growing and will grow extremely quickly in 2015? There's no downside.

Comment: didn't know that. Thought that HTTP/2 was not alive/useable/standardized before the 17th.

Comment: You're right. But is it backwards compatible with HTTP/1.1?

Comment: As soon as the first draft of [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-17) was written it was "usable." It doesn't matter if it's been standardized if browser vendors want implement it. We use lots of CSS3 features that only have draft specifications ([Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) comes to mind); why should HTTP/2 be any different?

Comment: "But is it backwards compatible with HTTP/1.1?" Browsers aren't going to stop supporting HTTP/1.1 any more than they stopped supporting HTTP/1.0 or HTML 3.2 or XHTML 1.0. HTTP servers aren't going to stop serving pages to browsers that don't speak HTTP/2. HTTP/1.1 isn't going away any time soon, but the existence of HTTP/2 doesn't cause problems for old browsers or for old servers.

Comment: Very fine answers. I didn't know these details. Thank you for your answers. I heard of HTTP/2.0 yesterday the first time, when I read about it. I never heard something about it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both servers and many UAs implement the HTTP/2 variant that was specified in an Internet Draft months ago. It's not materially different from the final HTTP/2 protocol, apart from the ALPN identifier naming the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the browsers (latest version) support the SPDY / HTTP 2.0 for some time, you can track this on http://caniuse.com/#search=spdy also handy for other web related technologies.

Besides, if the client does not support it the webserver replies in the "old" ways which is execelent to introduce new technologies.